# Law of Total Probability and Commas

Tags: probability, notation, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

I have a question regarding the use of commas when writing probabilities. In the following statement of the law of total probability for conditional probabilities, commas are used to describe unions, however the "order" of these unions isn't very clear.

[image]

On the last line, when $P(A|B_n,C)$ is written, how do we know if this means $P(A| (B_n \cap C))$ or $P((A|B_n) \cap C)$ ? Is there a specific rule for using commas in a certain way?

Comment: +1 to your posting.  In fact, the syntax is carelessly ambiguous.  My first try, blundering in the dark, would be that the **comma takes precedence**.  Then, I would examine the resulting assertion for plausibility and sensibility.

Comment: The issue is not commas or brackets or or orders of operations but the meaning of "$\mid$": here $A\mid B_n$ is not meaningful in the sense that there is no such event, at least not in the original probability space; in a restricted probability space where $P'(B_n)=1$ or $\Omega' = B_n$ the event could be written as $A$ or $A\cap B_n$.  Similarly  $(A\mid B_n) \cap C$ is not an event and $P((A\mid B_n) \cap C)$ does not have a sensible interpretation. Meanwhile $P(\cdots \mid \cdots)$ indicates a conditional probability so $P(A\mid (B_n \cap C))$ is meaningful, and is what is intended.

Comment: You write "*Commas are used to describe* **unions**"  This is wrong.  Commas are used to describe *intersections*.